# What does "if anything" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Suppose you work in a library, checking people's books as they leave,
> and a friend asks you to let him smuggle out a hard-to-find reference
> work that he wants to own. You might hesitate to agree for various
> reasons. You might be afraid that he'll be caught, and that both you
> and he will then get into trouble. You might want the book to stay in
> the library so that you can consult it yourself. But you may also
> think that what he proposes is wrong -- that he shouldn't do it and
> you shouldn't help him. If you think that, what does it mean, and
> what, if anything, makes it true?

What does it all mean? Thomas Nagel, Chapter 7

What does "if anything" mean in the context?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It means that there may not be anything that makes it true.

In general, "if anything" is inserted as a subordinate clause in a question about what things are in some way available, to acknowledge the possibility that nothing may be available.

Another way to put this particular sentence (though not a better way - the original is good) might be:

> Does anything make it true? If so (if anything makes it true), what (what thing(s))?